# PowerPoint - Add Set of Icons to Template Master for ease of use

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In PPT (latest version), I have a set of icons which I make use of on very many pages.

Is there a way that I can add this set of icons to the master template in a way that I have them always easily at hand?

Simply adding them in the Slide Master does not help since PPT puts them into the background, and, hence, does not allow me to easily select them while editing.

Comment: There are various add-ins that let you create your own libraries of images and other content. It might be worth looking for something like that.

Comment: Thanks - but I am hoping to include them into the master template by any means directly

Comment: Without an add-in, the best suggestion I can think of is to include sample slides (perhaps hidden) in your template. The slides could include whatever graphics you like. Users could then copy/paste them as needed, then later delete the "image library" slides or (since they're hidden) leave them as is.